# How do I rethrow SIGINT?

Tags: ruby, signals

What I currently have:

```
trap "SIGINT" do
  case ENV["MODE"]
  when "A"
    ...
  when "B"
    ...
  end
end
```

If I wanted to have no trap if `ENV["MODE"]` wasn't set, I would do:

```
trap "SIGINT" do
  case
    ...
  end
end if ENV["MODE"]
```

But what if I want to pass trap on a specific value?

```
trap "SIGINT" do
  case ENV["MODE"]
  when "A"
    ...
  when "B"
    ...
  when "C"
    # here I want to really do a SIGINT
  else
    # or here
  end
end
```

Comment: What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: Why not just replace `if ENV['MODE']` with `if ['A', 'B'].include ENV['MODE']`? But to answer your question - `Process.kill('INT', Process.pid)`.

Comment: @EricDuminil, to work similar to calling `raise` from between `rescue ... end`.

Comment: @ndn: your modified `if` is probably the best solution. I think `Process.kill('INT', Process.pid)` would get caught again by trap, though.

Comment: @EricDuminil, yea, makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

## Please

Please, just follow @ndn's advice to define `trap` inside `case` or `if` and not the other way around.

## Undefining `trap`

NOTE : **This is just a proof of concept!**

Calling `Process.kill('INT', Process.pid)` inside `when "C"` would just get caught in `trap` again. You need to undefine `trap` first. From the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Signal.html) :

> If the command is “DEFAULT” or “SIG_DFL”, the Ruby’s default handler
>   will be invoked.

Here's an example :

```
trap "SIGINT" do
  mode = %w(A B C D).sample
  puts "Sigint with mode : #{mode}"
  case mode
  when "A"
    puts "A, not exiting"
  when "B"
    puts "B, not exiting"
  when "C"
    puts "C, exiting"
    trap "SIGINT", "DEFAULT"
    Process.kill('INT', Process.pid)
  else
    puts "D, exiting"
    trap "SIGINT", "DEFAULT"
    Process.kill('INT', Process.pid)
  end
end

while true
  sleep 0.1
  p "+1"
end
```

It outputs :

```
"+1"
"+1"
"+1"
^CSigint with mode : A
A, not exiting
"+1"
"+1"
"+1"
"+1"
"+1"
"+1"
^CSigint with mode : C
C, exiting
trap_sigint.rb:21:in `sleep': Interrupt
    from trap_sigint.rb:21:in `<main>'
```

## Using `exit`

It isn't the same signal, but if you just want to stop execution of your script when mode is "C" or "D", you could use `exit` instead of `SIGINT` :

```
trap "SIGINT" do
  mode = %w(A B C D).sample
  puts "Sigint with mode : #{mode}"
  case mode
  when "A"
    puts "A, not exiting"
  when "B"
    puts "B, not exiting"
  when "C"
    puts "C, exiting"
    exit
  else
    puts "D, exiting"
    exit
  end
end

while true
  sleep 0.1
  p "+1"
end
```

It outputs

```
"+1"
"+1"
^CSigint with mode : A
A, not exiting
"+1"
"+1"
"+1"
"+1"
^CSigint with mode : B
B, not exiting
"+1"
"+1"
"+1"
"+1"
^CSigint with mode : D
D, exiting
```